# Format SOAP Message in a WebService asmx

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, asmx

I'm having troubles with the format required by our Client in a Webservice with SOAP 1.1 Messages, this is what he is expecting:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
    <SOAP-ENV:Body >
        <m:PingResponse xmlns:m="http://www.mycompany.com/service" Token="E30ED3AA-65DE-48F9-BEA4-BA021B119625" Echo="Hello!" Status="Successful" />
    </SOAP-ENV:Body >
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope >
```

And this is what I have until now

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <PingRequestResponse xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/service">
            <m:PingResponse Token="E30ED3AA-65DE-48F9-BEA4-BA021B119625" Status="Success" xmlns:m="http://www.mycompany.com/service" />
        </PingRequestResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is how I'm implementing

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mycompany.com/service")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public PingResponse PingRequest([XmlAttribute] string Token)
    {
        //do stuffs
        if (success) {
            return new PingResponse { Token = Token, Status = "Success" };
        }
        else {
            return new PingResponse { Token = Token, Status = "Failed", Error = new Error { Code = "NoConnection", Message = "Can't reach the server" } };
        }
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PingResponse", Namespace = "http://www.mycompany.com/service")]
public class PingResponse
{
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Token { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Error", Namespace = "http://www.mycompany.com/service")]
    public Error Error { get; set; }

    public PingResponse()
    {
        xmlns.Add("m", "http://www.mycompany.com/service");
    }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.mycompany.com/service")]
public class Error
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

So as you can see in my response is an aditional Xml element called **PingRequestResponse** generated by the WebService with the *MethodNameResponse* format, previously also i had another element called **PingRequestResult** below the PingRequestResponse, but I was able to remove it with the **[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PingResponse",** in my class

So I need to do the next:

- Remove the PingRequestResponse element and put the PingResponse directly below the body
- Change the namespace for the SOAP message (Envelope and Body) to "SOAP-ENV"
- Remove the xsi and xsd from the SOAP Message

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT:**

Until now I haven't the WSDL, so this is not a option for now

Comment: Ask for the WSDL and do a top down approach.

Comment: Yeah, I already asked for the WSDL some days ago, but until now I haven't

Answer (score 0):

I have spent lots of time in the past fighting the Net library adding xml namespaces.  When other method don't work I simply parse the string I need.  Much cleaner

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlStr =
                "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" >" +
                   "<SOAP-ENV:Body >" +
                      "<m:PingResponse xmlns:m=\"http://www.derbysoft.com/chapaai\"  />" +
                   "</SOAP-ENV:Body >" +
                "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope >";

            XElement envelope = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
            XElement response = envelope.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "PingResponse").FirstOrDefault();

            response.Add(new XAttribute("Token", "E30ED3AA-65DE-48F9-BEA4-BA021B119625"));
            response.Add(new XAttribute("Echo", "Hello"));
            response.Add(new XAttribute("Status", "Successful"));
        }

    }

}
```